# How do I make color the same even when overlapping two lines with transparent?

Tags: plotting, functions

How can I make them the same color even when overlapping? 
I want to use transparent to some degree.

```
Plot[{1 + x, 2 - x}, {x, 0, 1}, 
 PlotStyle -> 
  Directive[Red, Thickness[0.03], Opacity[0.3], CapForm["Round"]]]
```

[image]

Comment: use `PlotStyle ->  Directive[Blend[{Red, White}, .7], Thickness[0.03], CapForm["Round"]]`?

Answer (score 4):

> How can I make them the same color even when overlapping?

One possibility?

```
p1 = Plot[1 + x, {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> 
    Directive[Red, Thickness[0.03], Opacity[0.3], CapForm["Round"]]];
p2 = Plot[2 - x, {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> 
    Directive[Red, Thickness[0.03], Opacity[0.3], CapForm["Round"]]];

ImageCompose[Rasterize[p1], 
 ColorReplace[Rasterize[p2], White -> Transparent]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I think I didn't say it clearly. I actually want Opacity for the lines not the background.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a simplified function to mimic alpha blending:

```
alphaBlend[rgb_RGBColor, alpha_, back_ : White] := Blend[{rgb, back}, 1 - alpha]

Plot[{1 + x, 2 - x}, {x, 0, 1}, 
 PlotStyle -> 
  Directive[alphaBlend[Red, 0.3], Thickness[0.03], 
   CapForm["Round"]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can also account for the background color

```
Plot[{1 + x, 2 - x}, {x, 0, 1}, 
 PlotStyle -> 
  Directive[alphaBlend[Red, 0.3, LightBlue], Thickness[0.03], 
   CapForm["Round"]], Background -> LightBlue]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

(On preview this is basically what @kglr is saying)

Comment: But this is not transparent, like Opacity[0.3]. I think I didn't say it clearly. I actually want Opacity for the lines not the background.